# Flask jinja2 dict value by key

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, jinja2

I have list of dicts:

```
[{'row': '1', 'number': '5'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '10'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '3'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '7'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '2'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '13'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '6'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '12'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '1'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '8'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '9'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '11'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '15'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '14'}, {'row': '1', 'number': '4'}, {'row': '2', 'number': '1'}, {'row': '2', 'number': '4'}, {'row': '2', 'number': '10'}...]
```

I want to iterate thru this loop in jinja and print numbers inline for particular row#

Something like this:

```
<div class='row'>row#1 numbers for row #1: 1 2 3 4 ... </div>
<div class='row'>row#2 numbers for row #1: 1 2 3 4 ... </div>
<div class='row'>row#3 numbers for row #1: 1 2 3 4 ... </div>
```

I need divs as many unique rows in dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to reshape your dictionary so that the keys are the *row* and the values are the *number*, and then it will be easy to loop through this new dictionary and construct *divs*:

```
result = {}
for d in dd:          # dd is your list of dictionaries here
    result.setdefault(int(d['row']), []).append(d['number'])
​
result
#{'1': ['5',
#  '10',
#  '3',
#  '7',
#  '2',
#  '13',
#  '6',
#  '12',
#  '1',
#  '8',
#  '9',
#  '11',
#  '15',
#  '14',
#  '4'],
# '2': ['1', '4', '10']}
```

Comment: How i can sort it by int (rows and numbers inside each row)?

Comment: You can try this `{k: sorted(v, key=int) for k, v in result.items()}`

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/p8gNam1F3FVEtF - worked for numbers but not for the rows. Code inside Jinja: {% for row in result|sort %}
        <div class="row">
           row#{{ row }} numbers:{{ ' '.join(result[row]) }}
        </div>

{% endfor %}

Comment: Last question, how i can sort rows and numbers in result, which contains int and strings, like ['2', False], ['13', False]... ?  I got: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: A dictionary in python is orderless, i.e, you can't guarantee the order of key, so you can't sort the dictionary by a key, if you want the result to be ordered by row, you need an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or a list of tuples.for instance  `sorted((k, sorted(v, key=int)) for k, v in result.items())` gives you a list of tuples which are sorted by the first element and have sorted second element(list) as well, loop through this data structure should always give you ordered result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137799/discussion-between-konstantin-rusanov-and-psidom).

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 will have a tough time doing that on its own. You want to aggregate all the numbers for each row into a single list, and then print that list out. I recommend doing this in two separate steps.

```
row_dict = {}
for num_dict in list_of_dicts:
    row = num_dict['row']
    if row not in row_dict:
        row_dict[row] = []
    row_dict[row].append(num_dict['number'])
```

Now you've got a `row_dict` that looks like:

```
{
    '1': ['5', '10', '3', '7', '2', '13', '6', '12', '1', '8', '9', ...],
    '2': ['1', '4', '10', ...],
}
```

Jinja2 is fine to print this out. You could write a template that does something like this:

```
{% for row in row_dict.keys()|sort %}
<div class='row'>row#{{ row }} numbers for row #{{ row }}
  {{ ' '.join(row_dict[row]) }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```